# Some keyboard keys have been turned off

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry

I've been struggling for weeks with this problem: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>,<kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>,<kbd>FN</kbd>, and <kbd>WIN</kbd> keys are not working!

When I bring up the on-screen keyboard, those keys function correctly. When I connect an external keyboard to my laptop, the same problem occurs, so I think it's not a hardware problem.

I tried uninstalling the keyboard driver with no result.

When running Sharpkeys, a software that allows remapping Windows keys using the registry, I found out that those keys were in fact turned off. So I deleted under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` the item `Scancode Map`, but was only able to activate the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key.

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Yes, it does happen even in Safe mode.

Comment: Do you have any other items under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`? (I don't mean the sub-keys `DosKeybCodes` and `DosKeybIDs`).

Comment: No, just the default item with no value defined.